# How to make text field non editable

Tags: angularjs, uidatepicker

I have text field, which uses datepicker. I want text field should be non-editable so we can edit only using datepicker.

```
kindly have a look on 
http://plnkr.co/edit/zekPQhWK6SgWdK2phRnJ?p=preview
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: your plunker link is not working

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/zekPQhWK6SgWdK2phRnJ?p=preview

Comment: make input `readonly`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it using JavaScript, where i give the focus to the calendar check below: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p5QtXDdCFPv7TaEgJmBu?p=preview)

You can also call the button .click to open the calendar directly in the same function

```
<script>
  function RejectEnter()
  {
    document.getElementById("btnCal").focus();
   document.getElementById("btnCal").click();
    return false;
    }
```

and for the HTML:

```
 <input type="text" onfocus="return RejectEnter();" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" uib-datepicker-popup  is-open="popupDateFrom.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" id="btnCal" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Marking the input tag with **readonly** will serve the purpose.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };


  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
  };

  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.popupDateFrom.opened = true;
  };
  
  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popupDateTo.opened = true;
  };
  
  $scope.popupDateFrom = {
    opened: false
  };
  
  $scope.popupDateTo = {
    opened: false
  };


  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    }

    return '';
  }
 
});
```

```css
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt|date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</em></pre>

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" ng-model="dt" uib-datepicker-popup  is-open="popupDateFrom.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" ng-model="dt1" uib-datepicker-popup  is-open="popupDateTo.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>

    <hr />
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just making input box read-only is the easiest solution , i have tried your plunker, places just **readonly** input attribute and it works as desired result.

please have a look at the following line,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" uib-datepicker-popup  is-open="popupDateFrom.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
```

place readonly, above line will changed to this,

```
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" ng-model="dt" uib-datepicker-popup  is-open="popupDateFrom.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark the input as disabled. The users won't be able to click on it to edit its raw value, but they can open the datepicker.

Another aproach is to also open the datepicker whenever the user clicks on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to override the key events on the input control using javascript to prohibits manual input.

```
<input onkeydown="return false" ...... />
```